# Scala case class and private constructor element

Tags: scala, case-class

I want to be able to track number of task completed in some state machine (using Akka FSM), it's like joining N actions, started on transition from state A to B, in state B. So when all evens reach FSM on state B - it proceeds to state C.

I created very simple tracker for fork/join states.

```
  sealed trait ForkJoin {

    def join(): ForkJoin

  }

  case class Forks(forkNum: Int) extends ForkJoin {

    private var finished: Int = 0

    override def join = if (finished + 1 == forkNum) JoinComplete
    else {
      val f = Forks(forkNum)
      f.finished = finished + 1
      f
    }

  }

  case object JoinComplete extends ForkJoin {

    override def join = JoinComplete

  }
```

What I don't like there - pewsense of **var finished**. By it's nature it is **val**, however I have no idea how to make a private val and initialize it in **join** method.

I thought there is some way to make a constructor argument as *private*, not accessible from outside - but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to pass private arguments to `case classes`. It doesn't make sense, because the identity of an instance of a case class is defined over the passed constructor arguments. A private constructor argument would change the state but would not affect neither equality comparisons nor pattern matches.

What you can do is make the whole constructor `private`. To function properly as a FSM state you may need to implement `equals` and `hashCode` on your own [[1]](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/fsm.html#Defining_States).

```scala
sealed trait ForkJoin {
  def join(): ForkJoin
}

case class Forks private(forkNum: Int, finished: Int) extends ForkJoin{

  override def join =
    if (finished + 1 == forkNum)
      JoinComplete
    else
      Forks(forkNum, finished + 1)

  def copy(forkNum: Int = this.forkNum) = 
    Forks(forkNum, finished)

}

object Forks{
  def apply(forkNum: Int): Forks = Forks(forkNum, 0)
}

object JoinComplete extends ForkJoin {
  override def join = JoinComplete
}
```

Comment: but this will allow me to create an instance of Forks with arbitrary value for "finished", which I want to avoid.

Comment: I changed the answer accordingly, does this fit better?

Answer (score 1):

something like that?

```
sealed trait ForkJoin {
    def join(): ForkJoin
 }

  case class Forks(forkNum: Int, finished: Int = 0) extends ForkJoin {
    override def join = if (finished + 1 == forkNum) JoinComplete
    else Forks(forkNum, finished + 1)
   }

  case object JoinComplete extends ForkJoin {
    override def join = JoinComplete
  }
```

Comment: (though I think your join() method in trait and in object can also return `this`)

Comment: In this way it is possible to override current joins number in the object and pass it to states, which I really want to avoid.